# Least degree of a Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

I came in contact with a question from the Math Brazilian Olympiad that asks to find a the least degree of a polynomial $p(x)$, monic with integer coefficients, such that $p(n)$ is a multiple of 2021 for every positive integer n.

I thought but I couldn't even start.

I think it does have something to do with the factorization of 2021 as 2021 = 43*41, and then then 41 | $p(n)$ and 43 | $p(n)$ also.

Comment: You mean $43 \times 47.$

Comment: $$\prod_{i=1}^{47} (x - i)$$ certainly works, since the product of any $k$ consecutive integers is a multiple of $k$.  So, the trick may be to prove that no polynomial of degree $(46)$ can work, re modulo $(47)$.  Actually, I have no opinion whether $(47)$ is the maximum degree needed.

Comment: I didn't comprehend your argument, what does $k$ have to do?

Comment: Let $k$ be any **fixed** positive integer.  Consider the function $$f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^k \left(x - i\right).$$  Now, consider the sequence of elements given by $$\{f(1), f(2), f(3), \cdots\}.$$  The first $(k)$ elements in this sequence will all be $(0)$.  Thereafter, each element in the sequence will represent the product of $(k)$ consecutive integers, and thus each subsequent element in the sequence will be a multiple of $(k)$.

Comment: I still don't comprehend well.

Comment: Sometimes, the biggest obstacle to the Math student's learning process is the Math student's own sense of identify.  This is obviously not the time to strive for elegance.  Set $(k) = 5$ (for example), take out a piece of scratch paper, and manually calculate the first $(10)$ elements in the sequence $$\{f(1), f(2), f(3), \cdots, f(10)\}.$$  You should see a pattern in the data that you can study and then explain to yourself.  Each non-zero element will be a multiple of $(5)$.  This is a time for **Elbow Grease**, rather than elegance.

Comment: I comprehended, but in the question it asks for all $n$ and $p(1)$ till $p(k)$ will be zero, how does it continue?

Comment: Set $$f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{47} \left(x - i\right).$$ Each element in the set $$\{f(1), f(2), \cdots, f(47)\}$$ will equal $(0)$.  Each element in the set $$\{f(48), f(49), \cdots, f(94)\}$$ will contain the factor $(47)$.  Each element in the set $$\{f(95), f(96), \cdots, f(141)\}$$ will contain the factor $(94)$.  And so forth.

Comment: Now I comprehend, I just forgot that 0 is a multiple of 2021.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, suppose $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a polynomial and $p$ is a prime such that $p \mid f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. What can we say about $f$? This is equivalent to the condition that the reduction $\bmod p$ of $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ which vanishes on $\mathbb{F}_p$, and any such polynomial must be divisible by

$$\prod_{i \in \mathbb{F}_p} (x - i) = x^p - x$$

and in particular must have degree at least $p$.

Since $2021 = 43 \times 47$ we conclude that if $2021 \mid f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $f(x)$ must have degree at least $\boxed{47}$, and then $\prod_{i=1}^{47} (x - i)$ works as user 2661923 observes in the comments.

Comment: How did you conclude that part which says: "...must have degree at least 47..."?

Comment: @stackexchange: apply the first half of the answer to $p = 47$.

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: What is not clear? The argument shows that $f(x) \bmod p$ must be divisible by $x^p - x$, so $f(x) \bmod p$ must have degree at least $p$, so $f(x)$ must have degree at least $p$. Which step of this argument are you having trouble with?

Comment: The choice of $p$ being 47 and not, for example, 43.

Comment: The argument also applies to $43$; we get that the degree of $f(x)$ is also at least $43$. However, since applying the argument to $47$ gets a better bound this bound doesn't matter.